# How to set the x-axis to be inconsistent in Android mpchart?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the X-axis interval to be inconsistent in Android using mpchart as shown in the picture below?
For example, instead of 10, 20, 30, 40, is it possible to set each column of the
Or should I use another library?
thank you

[image]